# Email campaign & response capture software self hosted

Tags: email

We are looking for a software package that will facilitate:-

**Creation and distribution of marketing emails**

- personalised content per email 
  (e.g. Dear [user], hyperlinks in message with unique identifers so that hosted web pages can identify user to capture their responses)
- Messages contain Outlook HTML (Word HTML), embedded and hosted images
- Mail sent via our own SMTP gateway

**Website to capture responses**

- A solution that we can host as campaigns.[ourdomain].com
- Identify and greet user based on unique identifier from emails
- Allow capture and validation of additional form data per email campaign
- Prevent multiple responses
- Prevent submission after event
- Response data is stored and/or submitted by email

Is there such a software package available. I know there are various hosted solutions that provide most of these requirements but we need in-house solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using [Dada Mail](http://dadamailproject.com/) for this.  It's not exactly what you want, but it's close, and you can extend it to meet your requirements fully.

Here is a breakdown of how it meets your requirements, and where it falls short:

**Creation and distribution of marketing emails**

- **personalised content per email** - Dada Mail calls this "Subscriber Profiles"
- **Messages contain Outlook HTML (Word HTML), embedded and hosted images** - I don't know if the Dada Mail message compose page will do "Word HTML", but you can compose a message in Word/Outlook and copy in in there.  Alternatively, you can use "Dada Bridge" to compose the message in your own email client and send it to Dada Mail, which will redistribute it to your email list.
- **Mail sent via our own SMTP gateway** - Dada Mail has full support for this, via `sendmail` or direct SMTP.

**Website to capture responses**

- **A solution that we can host as campaigns.[ourdomain].com** - Dada Mail can be hosted at any (sub)domain that you own.
- **Identify and greet user based on unique identifier from emails** - Dor each link in your email, Dada Mail's "Clickthrough Tracker" can generate a unique URL for every user, so that each user's click goes to that unique URL.

The rest of these requirements are not built into Dada Mail.  However, you can build a separate simple application that connects to the Dada Mail database to get the user's information and does all of these things, then have the links in your Dada Mail messages go through to that site.  It's not a one-click solution, but it's what I use and it works pretty well for me.

- Allow capture and validation of additional form data per email campaign
- Prevent multiple responses
- Prevent submission after event
- Response data is stored and/or submitted by email